# MySQL query with date parameter

Tags: php, mysql, date

My table in mysql has special data stamp (*startdata*). It is date when event starts. Older events stored in database to, but i don't need them to appear in the MySQL answer. 
So is there any way sending query to database that includes parameter i need? (for example, not showing rows where startdate older than today).

Now my code looks like:

```
$res3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM raspisanie WHERE
instr='" . $instrument . "' AND school IN(" . $array2 . ") 
AND type='regular' AND state='1' ORDER by startdate");
```

Comment: `where startdate > now()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add condition in your where clause.

```
    $res3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM raspisanie WHERE
    instr='" . $instrument . "' AND school IN(" . $array2 . ") 
    AND type='regular' AND state='1' AND startdate >now() ORDER by startdate");
```